# Keyboard shortcut for lsp-lens

Tags: lsp-mode

I'm trying to use `lsp-lens` mode but it only allows you to activate lenses with mouse (or avy, which IMO is not convenient). I was unable to find a way to activate lenses with some keyboard shortcut (for example some shortcut which would open helm menu with available lenses). I cannot move cursor to required lens, it is going to next line (in my case right after `]`). I was also unable to even find out which elisp function is called for lenses.

[image]

Maybe I missing something? Even a little hint of how to call lenses from elisp would be helpful, from there I could write necessary code to bind lenses to keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: I'd try taking a look at avy's code and seeing what that does.

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert here but here is how I'd do it, from what i read from the code:

1. The lenses are implemented as overlays, stored as a list : lsp-lens--overlays
2. Get the LSP metadata from each overlay

   (overlay-get overlay 'lsp--metadata)
3. These metadata can have several lens tokens, from which you can get the associated action

   (get-text-property 0 'action lens-token)
4. To call the associated action

   (funcall-interactively action)
5. The hard part will be the UI, because you have to make it clear which overlay of which line you will be executing. Maybe something with vertico with livepreview, starting on your current line, would be nice ? Anyway I don't blame the devs of lsp-mode, in the end the UI with avy gets the job done.

Here is the relavant snippet from lsp-avy-lens in lsp-lens.el

```
(-mapcat                                                                                                                                                                                     
  (lambda (overlay)                                                                                                                                                                           
    (-map-indexed                                                                                                                                                                             
      (lambda (index lens-token)                                                                                                                                                               
        (list overlay index                                                                                                                                                                    
          (get-text-property 0 'action lens-token)))                                                                                                                                       
      (overlay-get overlay 'lsp--metadata)))                                                                                                                                                   
  lsp-lens--overlays)
```